# File could not be parsed as a strings file [R.swift]

Tags: swift, xcode, localization, r.swift

I'm using R.swift and suddenly I got this error:

`warning: [R.swift] File could not be parsed as a strings file: "File URL"`

Answer (score 0):

It was an actual syntax error in the `Localized.strings` file.

> "key" = "value"

instead of:

> "key" : "value"